# How to enable Cloud Foundry's sticky session in Python Flask project?

Tags: python, session, cloud-foundry

I am developing an app to run in Cloud Foundry using python. When I was trying to scale up the instances, I found that the client request was routed to different instances each time in a round-robin way. However, my app has kept data in session, which requires consistency between the requests.

I found the document from CloudFoundry which introduces the jsessionid to make it consistent. https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html#sessions

Here are the code snippet I wrote to test the sticky session. But it does not work even if I put a jsessionid in cookie. Can anyone help on it? Thanks

```
@app.route('/') 
def sticky_session():
    ret = "VCAP_APPLICATION env var: <br/>" + os.getenv("VCAP_APPLICATION", "") + "<br/>"
    ret += "<br/>"
    ret += "Port: " + os.getenv('PORT', '5000') + "<br/>"
    resp = make_response(ret)
    resp.set_cookie('jsessionid', 'your secret here.')
    session['test'] = 'test'
    return resp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It finally works. The only difference is that the cookie is case sensitive and should be in upper case.

```
resp.set_cookie('JSESSIONID', 'your secret here.')
```